# CiviMail causes read timeout on Methods.pm

Tags: civimail

Version 4.6.9

When a scheduled bulk email is sent, Cron Daemon returns `read timeout at /usr/local/share/perl5/Net/HTTP/Methods.pm line 271.` Line 271 is inside the function sub my_readline. This has been going on for about a week, but it's been months since I've done any settings changes on the server.

Email delivery is unaffected according to CiviMail reports. I get this multiple times if sending lasts for multiple cron cycles. The Send Scheduled Mailings job shows no anomalies. Does anyone have experience resolving this error?

Comment: Curious. Followup questions: (a) `Methods.pm` is a Perl thing, and the normal Civi stuff is PHP+JS.  Any idea what process is calling Perl? (b) How is outbound mail configured? SMTP? Sendmail? Something else?

Comment: a) Good question, I'm stumped. I've done no work with Perl. b) SMTP via CiviSMTP.

Comment: I realize this is a very old question, but we have a similar issue with a nearly identical error message. Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: I never did resolve it in a way that allowed proper mail delivery. Changing the Outbound Mail selection from SMTP to mail() did stop the server from generating error report emails, but mail delivery suffered.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your site or hosting environment runs cron via some Perl wrapper.

You may need to talk to your hosts about hitting this timeout when cron tasks are running - if they call cron via a web based tool which times out after a few minutes, that tool may not be suitable for running Drupal cron.

Talk to your hosting experts and see if they can help?